# SSRS: Export to Excel

Tags: excel, reporting-services

Good morning.
I have a report in SSRS with a header that has an image and a title. When exporting the data to Excel, it generates an extra column at the end of the image, making the data below separate. How can I solve that? I tried to play with the alignment and even put the image inside a rectangle but it keeps doing the same thing. Could you help me?